# Programmatically Create Popover Menu Swift

Tags: ios, swift

Desired Popover Output:

[image]

I tried following the tutorial [here](http://gracefullycoded.com/display-a-popover-in-swift/)... However, I can't seem to get this working

Current Code:

```
  func adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController(
    controller: UIPresentationController!) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {
        return .None
}

@IBAction func UploadClicked(sender: AnyObject)
{

    let menuViewController =  MenuViewController()
    menuViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .Popover
    menuViewController.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(50, 100)

    let popoverMenuViewController = menuViewController.popoverPresentationController
    popoverMenuViewController?.permittedArrowDirections = .Any
    popoverMenuViewController?.delegate = self
    popoverMenuViewController?.sourceView = sender
    popoverMenuViewController?.sourceRect = CGRect(
        x: location.x,
        y: location.y,
        width: 1,
        height: 1)
    presentViewController(
        menuViewController,
        animated: true,
        completion: nil)
}
```

> Use of unresolved identifier menuviewcontroller
>
> Use of unresolved identifier location

Comment: please use the correct case for the error messages, is the variable missing or the class!?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem has not any to do with the presentation of the Popover, your error says :

> **Use of unresolved identifier menuviewcontroller**

You need to instantiate your `UIViewController` like in the following way:

```
// Set the name of your Storyboard here
let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

// Instantiate your UIViewController
let menuViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MenuViewController") as! MenuViewController
```

Before do it the above code you need to set the **StoryBoardID** in the IdentityInspector in Interface Builder like in the following picture:

[image]

I hope this help you.

Comment: This loads my viewdidload in my viewcontroller again which is calling multiple database queries... I want to avoid reloading the parent view(main view)?

Comment: First of all, I solve your question, what you want to achieve is another question, is not a good behavior remove the answer because you notice that you have another problem different when you solve the first.

Comment: any idea as to why my viewdidload is being called again?

Comment: Is the normal behaviour that every time you instantiate an `ViewController` the `viewDidLoad` is called, you need to separate the layers in your case to keep a Data Access Layer or something else and make a kind of cache in which if you data was previously loaded not load it again.